# Modifying a rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have the following route:

```
resources :trees, shallow: true, controller: 'base', param: :ed_node_id, only: %i[index show] do
        resources :courses, shallow: true, controller: 'base', param: :ed_node_id, only: %i[index show]
end
```

Which gives me:

```
api_v1_tree_courses GET    /api/v1/trees/:tree_ed_node_id/courses(.:format)                                         
api_v1_course GET    /api/v1/courses/:ed_node_id(.:format)
api_v1_trees GET    /api/v1/trees(.:format)                                                                  
api_v1_tree GET    /api/v1/trees/:ed_node_id(.:format)
```

What i’m trying to avoid is on that first route, the param not being prefixed by `:tree`. Is there a way in nested routes to force the param not to have a parent route prefix or possibly using a regex to give the desired route?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Rails just generates the param key for nested resources by [combining the singular form of the name with the param option](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d239f7c1407bd6632aeb1fdf18b456de6c3c3972/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1158):

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    module Mapper
       class Resource 
          ...
          def nested_param
            :"#{singular}_#{param}"
          end
       end
     end
  end
end
```

There is no option to actually alter the entire nested param - it would make a good feature request though.

The alternative is to use scope:

```
resources :trees, only: :index

scope '/trees/:ed_node_id' do
  resources :courses, 
    only: :index, 
    as: :tree_courses
end

# shallow nesting won't work so we have to define this separately.
resources :courses, only: [:show]
```